# jquery - how can I access a variable which is defined later by click function?

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $newdiv;
    var clck = 16;

    for (var i = 0; i < clck; i++) {
        $newdiv = $('<div class="ball" />').fadeIn(500 * i);
        $('#all').append($newdiv);
    }

    $('.ball').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor' : "#b0e0e6"}, 500);
    });

    $('#but1').click(function() {
        $('.ball').remove();
        clck = prompt("Insert #..", "max. 64");
    });

    $('#pall').html("this is..." + clck);
});
```

..and what I don't know is, how to redefine a "clck" variable with a prompt in a click function, so that i have that new number in a for loop at the beginning. Is it possible to do that?
..that last command is there just to see if it's working outside the click function, 'cause if you add an alert inside that function you get your number. It seems to not work only outside it, despite it's a global variable.
..I was searching for an answer for 2 days and found nothing which would work..
..thank you for your answer, and please sorry for my english

Comment: *"Is it possible to do that?"* No. You can't go back in time. You might want to learn about functions. You could put the `for` loop inside a function and then simply call it again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

No. You can't go back in time. You might want to learn about [**functions**](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions). You could put the `for` loop inside a function and then simply call it again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $newdiv;

    function append(clck) {
        for (var i = 0; i < clck; i++) {
            $newdiv = $('<div class="ball" />').fadeIn(500 * i);
            $('#all').append($newdiv);
        }
    }

    append(16);

    $('.ball').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor' : "#b0e0e6"}, 500);
    });

    $('#but1').click(function() {
        $('.ball').remove();
        append(prompt("Insert #..", "max. 64"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You must use .live()
[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: a) `.live` is deprecated (and remove). b) It has nothing to do **at all** with the issue here. Please read the whole question, not just the title (although even the title doesn't suggest that `.live` could be a solution).

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding the problem. It has nothing to do with event handling, only with how code is processed. Here is simplified example: `var foo = 5; alert(foo); foo = 42;`. The OP wants to magically go back to line 2 (`alert(foo);`) and execute it again after `foo` changed. That's not possible.